# Extract specific data from an embedded javascript in webpage

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, lxml

I want to extract only the latitudes from the link: "http://hdfc.com/branch-locator"  using the method given below.
The latitudes are given inside a javascript variable called 'location'.
The code is:

```
from lxml import html
import re

URL = "http://hdfc.com/branch-locator"
var_lat = re.compile('(?<="latitude":).+(?=")')

main_page = html.parse(URL).getroot()

lat = main_page.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']")[1]

ans = re.search(var_lat,str(lat))

print ans
```

But the output comes as "None". What changes should I make to the code without changing the approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think a few small changes are required

in the line

```
lat = main_page.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']")[1] # This should be 10
```

The line

```
ans = re.search(var_lat,str(lat))
```

should be

```
ans = re.search(var_lat, lat.text)
```

`str(lat)` is going to call `__str__` function of the object `lat`, which is not same as `lat.text`

In general a good idea to actually go through all lats first and then go about searching for the desired string. So this should be -

```
lat = main_page.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']")
for l in lat:
    if l.text is None:
        continue
    # print l.text
    ans = re.search(var_lat,(l.text))
    if ans is not None:
        break

print ans
```

Sorry, edited to fix the issue. Note: This may not be the exact solution you want - but should give you the first instance where the required regex is matched. You might want to process `ans` further.

Comment: Nope, not working. It is showing this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "hdfcspider.py", line 13, in <module>
        ans = re.search(var_lat, l.text)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
        return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Fixed - error - it isn't a 'final answer' just an approach, should help you solve the remaining part.

Answer (score 0):

The code that I have written below works for an embedded javascript in a webpage.

```
from lxml import html
from json import dump
import re

dumped_data = []

class theAddress:
    latude = ""

URL = "http://hdfc.com/branch-locator"
var_lat = re.compile('(?<="latitude":").+?(?=")')

main_page = html.parse(URL).getroot()

residue = main_page.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()")[1]
all_latude = re.findall(var_lat,residue)

for i in range(len(all_latude)):
    obj = theAddress()
    obj.latude = all_latude[i]

    dumped_data.append(obj.__dict__)

f = open('hdfc_add.json','w')
dump(dumped_data, f, indent = 1)
```

It also makes use of json module to store scraped data in a proper format.